# Locale not being set on initial login on Raspbian/Debian

Tags: debian, ssh, locale, putty, raspbian

When I log in to my headless Raspbian box using putty/ssh, the locale is not being set correctly.

However, if I `su` to another user, then `su` back, the locales are then set.

This session shows the behaviour.

```
pi@raspberrypi(~)$ locale
LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
  … more LC_* environment set to POSIX
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
pi@raspberrypi(~)$ su XX
Password:
XX@raspberrypi /home/pi $ locale
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
  … more LC_* environment set to en_GB.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8
XX@raspberrypi /home/pi $ su pi
Password:
pi@raspberrypi(~)$ locale
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_GB.UTF-8
  … more LC_* environment set to en_GB.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8
```

**Note**
`locale charmap` returns `ANSI_X3.4-1968` before `su`'ing to another user then back.
After, `locale charmap` returns the intended `UTF-8`

Also, putty translation is set to `UTF-8`

Comment: Please don't use pastebin when you could easily paste the text into the question directly. I fixed it for you. At least you didn't use screenshots as some new users like to do for simple text. ;)

Comment: The answers to [this question on serverfault](http://serverfault.com/q/466316/169422) may also solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The user `pi` does not have `LC_ALL` set in its startup files. The user `XX` does, and every shell subordinate to `su XX` will inherit the value of `LC_ALL`.

Find the line `export LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8` in the .profile/.login/.bashrc/etc. of user `XX` and add that to the same place in user `pi`.

You might also want to look for something like `/etc/default/locale` which contains a system-wide locale. I don't know where raspbian stores that (if it does).

Comment: I've done a little more digging and it seems to be a problem with the putty client itself. When logging in with any user(eg. with XX first), the behaviour is the same( `POSIX` for most entries)

Answer (score 0):

In RaspBMC I've added the line:

```
export LC_TYPE=ru_UA.UTF-8 LC_ALL=ru_UA.UTF-8 LANG=ru_UA.UTF-8
```

at the end of `/home/pi/.bashrc` file.

This works, if one wants to see Cyrillic file names (particularly in Midnight Commander) after logging as default 'pi' user via PuTTY from Windows. No `su`ing, as it was described above, is needed anymore.